# Phpstorm 7, LiveEdit - configuring Chrome extention JetBrains IDE Support to run remotely

Tags: google-chrome, networking, ide, phpstorm, liveedit

I want to see how the website is changing while I'm coding and I want to see this on the screen of the other machine (with Chrome browser opened).
There is an option to change IP and PORT in JetBrains IDE Support extention. I'm pasting there the IP of the machine where I'm using Phpstorm 7. But the extention is not working, it cannot connect to the IDE via LAN. I checked all firewall options, I was trying to turn off the firewall, I was checking all opened ports in the OS and it still doesn't work. Can anybody help me with this ?

Please do not suggest plugging in the other screen or using some screen expanding via network.

Info of my apps and plugins:

PHP Storm 7
LiveEdit 1.11.131
JetBrains IDE Support extention for Chrome 1.27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Settings/JavaScript/Debugger specify the same port as you have specified in JetBrains IDE Support extention settings; make sure to turn 'Can accept external connections'. This should do the thing

Comment: I had the same settings and it didn't work but it started working after I restart both pc's. Thank you !